# Error in triggers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger that should be fired once an Update in the Table intradayOHLC occurs the old and the new must be inserted in the OHLC_update

Can someone please check the trigger and tell me where is the error

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr1
ON [Transaction].[IntradayOHLC]
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[IntradayOHLC_update] 
    VALUES(Symbol, Date, GetDate(), [Open], High, Low, Volume, newOpen, newHigh, newLow, newVolume);

    SELECT Symbol, date, [Open], Low, Volume FROM DELETED;
    SELECT newOpen, newLow, newVolume FROM INSERTED;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `INSERT` from `SELECT` syntax

If you want to insert the `old` and `new` values from Inserted and Deleted table then you should join both the tables.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[intradayohlc_update] 
            (symbol, 
             date,
             .....) 
SELECT d.symbol, 
       d.date, 
       Getdate(), 
       d.[open], 
       d.low, 
       d.volume, 
       i.newopen, 
       i.newlow, 
       i.newvolume 
FROM   deleted d 
       INNER JOIN inserted i 
               ON d.primary_key_col = i.primary_key_col
```

Comment: I tried it but it's giving me an invalid object name 'deleted'